# Can't connect to iDrac via putty

Tags: drac

I have a Dell R620 server for which iDrac has become completely bricked. I have literally tried everything else and am wanting to flash it through TFTP, but, when I connect to the serial port from an other laptop, I can see post messages in putty, but I can't get to the RAC recovery mode at all...

I have set the redirection with console on com 2 in BIOS but just can't get the console up.

Does anyone have any thoughts on that?

Flashing any other way has failed as iDrac is bricked.

Comment: Try resetting the iDRAC with the i-button - https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln305793/how-to-reset-the-internal-dell-remote-access-controller-idrac-on-a-poweredge-server-?lang=en

Comment: hello @joeqwerty, I tried, but it doesn't help. Tried tons of stuff...